# Linux framebuffer viewer

Tags: linux, framebuffer

I want to test some text drawing functions on a framebuffer device that is not connected to any physical display. Is there a way to view in real time what I'm drawing to /dev/fb0 ?

Answer (score 3):

picoTK comes with a small framebuffer emulator:

http://picotk.sourceforge.net/

http://sixpak.org/fbe/

Although it is quite old, it served me well some years ago.